# Why does my code in my c# windows form not work?

Tags: c#

Why does my grid view not refresh with data in it? It adds to the database but then clears my grid view and has nothing in it. It loads the form and I can enter information into it hit the add button and it adds to database but grid view refresh puts no data into it.

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = titleTextBox.Text;
        string starring = starringTextBox.Text;
        string year = yearTextBox.Text;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=<PATH TO FILE>);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Movie (Title, Starring, Year) VALUES (@title, @starring, @year)";            
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Starring", starring);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", year);

        cmd.Connection = conn;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn);

        titleTextBox.Text = "";
        starringTextBox.Text = "";
        yearTextBox.Text = "";
        titleTextBox.Focus();

        movieTableAdapter.Fill(moviesDataSet.Movie);
        movieBindingSource.DataSource = movieTableAdapter;
        myDataGridView.DataSource = movieBindingSource;
        myDataGridView.Refresh();
        myDataGridView.Update();

        conn.Close();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'moviesDataSet.Movie' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.movieTableAdapter.Fill(this.moviesDataSet.Movie);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select query here", conn);
```

Pass select query to adapter. You are passing an insert query.

Comment: @user200124 also wrap that connection in a using statement `using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=<PATH TO FILE>)) {  }`